# Why is NSolve finding different # of roots for algebraic function?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Consider roots of $f(u)=u^{-1/4}-2/15 u-1/6$ which can be written as
$$
u^{-1/4}e^{-1/4 (2n \pi i)}-2/15 u-1/6=0
$$
where $u^{-1/4}$ is taken as principal-value.  Or as a GroebenerBasis:

$$
f(u)=-810000 + 625 u + 2000 u^2 + 2400 u^3 + 1280 u^4 + 256 u^5=0
$$
which has five solutions.  I was wondering if someone could explain to me why when I use NSolve to solve $u^{-1/4}e^{-1/4 (2n \pi i)}-2/15 u-1/6=0$, it returns two solutions for n=2 but only one solution for n=0,1,3?

```
theK[n_] := Exp[-1/4 2 n Pi I];
theUVals = (u /. 
     NSolve[u^(-1/4) theK[#] - 2/15 u - 1/6 == 0, u] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3})

{{4.04009},
{0.554451 -4.74207 I},
{-5.0745-2.93375 I,-5.0745+2.93375 I},
{0.554451 +4.74207 I}}
```

**Update as per comment below:**

I can back-substitute the five solutions into the original equation but must use the branch form $u^{-1/4}=u^{-1/4}e^{-1/4(2 n\pi i)}$ to do so as Mathematica I believe, will interpret the naked $u^{-1/4}$ expression as principal-value:

```
MapThread[(#1^(-1/4) theK[#2] - 2/15 #1 - 
    1/6) &, {theUVals, {0, 1, 2, 3}}]

    {{8.32667*10^-17},
{2.77556*10^-17+2.22045*10^-16 I},
{-6.93889*10^-16+1.55431*10^-15 I,-6.93889*10^-16-1.55431*10^-15 I}, 
 {2.77556*10^-17-2.22045*10^-16 I}}
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting your five solutions back into your original equation?

Comment: Yes.  Updated post above.

Comment: *Mathematica* cannot read your mind. If you want to solve an equation involving a multivalued function, you must ask for the solution for each value. Or, in some special cases like this one, use `VerifySolutions->False`.

Comment: Ok.  My main question though is why is NSolve returning two solutions for a single branch $u^{-1/4(4 \pi i)}$  and single solutions for the other branches?

Comment: Why do both solutions satisfy the equation in that case?

Comment: Afraid I made a syntax error above.  Should have read: "for the branch $u^{-1/4}e^{-1/4(4\pi i)}$ but don't want to delete it for the record.  However, not quite sure why two solutions satisfy that case.  The branch coefficient $e^{-1/4(4 \pi i)}$ simply places a negative sign on the root expression resulting in $-u^{-1/4}-2/15 u-1/6=0$.  Need to study it a bit.

Comment: Hint: your fourth root has four branches, but your quintic has five roots. This is apparently a mathematics question, not a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: Perhaps so.  Sorry.  I do understand why if $a+bi$ is a solution to $-u^{-1/4}-2/15 u-1/6$, when $u^{-1/4}$ is interpreted as the principal value, then it's easy to show that $a-bi$ is also a solution simply by letting the principal value $(c+di)^{-1/4}=x+iy$ then $(c-di)^{-1/4}=x-iy$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppressing solution verification, using `Solve` and `RootReduce` to get true zeros, and substituting the results back into the equation, I get:

```
u^(-1/4) theK[2] - 2/15 u - 1/6 /. Solve[u^(-1/4) theK[2] - 2/15 u - 1/6 == 0, u, 
VerifySolutions -> False] // RootReduce // N
(* {-1.41069, 0., 0., -0.87287 + 0.391683 I, -0.87287 - 0.391683 I} *)
```

for case 2. So, in that case, only two of the five roots you get from using the inverse of the fourth root to make a polynomial actually solve the original equation. For other cases, only one solution works. The default for `VerifySolutions` is rejecting the others.

Comment: But my back-substitution for all five solutions  above satisfies the original branch expression (numerically) using the factor $e^{-1/4(2n\pi i)}$.  Bit confusing to me.